# Tensorflow_core._api.v2.train has no attribute 'slice_input_producer'

Tags: python, tensorflow

**When using**

```
image = tf.cast(image, tf.string)
label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)
# make a input queue
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image, label])
```

In my VSCode the following Error pops up:

> module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.train' has no attribute
>   'slice_input_producer' TF version 2.0

Do you think the only possibility is to downgrade the TF version?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try using `tf.compat.v1.train.slice_input_producer`?